# Adding a failure to SoftAssertions from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency, assertj

`SoftAssertions` in *AssertJ* is useful when I need to make sure multiple conditions hold or collect as many failures as possible:

```
        final SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();

        softly.assertThat("foo").hasToString("foo");
        softly.assertThat("bar").hasToString("bar");

        softly.assertAll();
```

Still, things no longer look that rosy when it comes to multi-threaded environment, when I need to collect failures produced in multiple threads. For example, this code is broken because changes made to the `SoftAssertions` instance from other threads might not be visible from the `main` thread:

```
        final SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();

        final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        forkJoinPool.execute(() -> {
            softly.assertThat("foo").hasToString("foo");
        });
        forkJoinPool.execute(() -> {
            softly.assertThat("bar").hasToString("bar");
        });

        softly.assertAll();
```

What is the best approach to solve the above problem?

Guarding `SoftAssertions` with a synchronized block wherever I'm using them doesn't seem like a good solution (especially from test readability standpoint).